How to Copy Data from primary eventhub to secondary
I am exploring about the data transfer from one eventhub to another eventhub but both are paired using Geo-Recovery since it wont replicate the data from primary to secondary want to copy the message data from primary eventhub to secondary how it practically possible by following approaches. can some one help me to get some information

Stream Analytics
Azure Function Apps
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-messaging-replication-dotnet/blob/main/functions/config/EventHubCopy/README.md


since Geo-DR only replicates metadata, not event data.  For replicating event data and operating corresponding namespaces in active/active configurations to cope with outages and disasters, don't lean on this Geo-disaster recovery feature set, but follow the replication guidance.

The Geo-DR  feature enables instantaneous continuity of operations with the same configuration, but does not replicate the event data. Unless the disaster caused the loss of all zones, the event data that is preserved in the primary Event Hub after failover will be recoverable and the historic events can be obtained from there once access is restored.

Geo-Disaster Recovery (Geo-DR) in Azure Event Hubs is used to ensure high availability and resilience in the event of a regional outage or disaster.
Geo-DR does not replicate data between the primary and secondary namespaces.


From the MSDOC
The feature enables instantaneous continuity of operations with the same configuration, but does not replicate the event data.


Using Geo-Recovery for replicate the data from primary to secondary want to copy the message data from primary eventhub to secondary is not possible . Since we have read-only access to the secondary namespace. Secondary namespace is read-only. So  we can use   different Event Hub in order to copy other than secondary.
I Used this MSDOC   to Event replication tasks using  Azure Event Hubs
The code  for  Azure Messaging Replication Tasks with .NET in azure function app taken from  git
The below  Function App code in git   for  processing  data from a source Event Hub and sending it to a target Event Hub .
Using Azure Function :

I refer this MSDOC  for Process data using Stream Analytics  with  Azure Event Hubs
